# Как преобразовать файл формата .ogg в .wav ? Файл .ogg с Telegram

Tags: python, аудио, subprocess, wav, ogg

Файл .ogg с Telegram

```
import speech_recognition as SRG
import subprocess

src_filename = 'voice.ogg'
dest_filename = 'voice.wav'
process = subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', src_filename, dest_filename])

store = SRG.Recognizer()
voice = open("voice.wav", "rb")
with SRG.AudioFile(voice) as source :
    audio_input = store.record(source)
    try:
        text_output = store.recognize_google(audio_input, language='ru')
        print(text_output)
    except:
           print("Couldn't process the audio input.")
```

Вот весь код. Гуглю уже пару часов, но никак не могу найти ответ...
При запуске выдает FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл.
Может проблема в путе к файлу ?
Хотя все файлы находятся в одной папке.
Вот полный код ошибки :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\recognizing\bot1.py", line 6, in <module>
    process = subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', src_filename, dest_filename])
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: А `ffmpeg` у вас точно есть? И он доступен из того каталога, из которого запускается бот?

Comment: А как проверить может ли ffmpeg запускаться в даном каталоге ?

Comment: Запустить командную строку, перейти в этот каталог, набрать `ffmpeg` и запустить. Возможно, отругается, что не может найти файл. Надо тогда в путях прописать его или указать к нему полный путь. Но может и не в этом дело.

Comment: Не помогло :(((

Answer (score 0):

```
import soundfile as sf                            #   pip install pysoundfile

data, samplerate = sf.read('existing_file.ogg')
sf.write('new_file.wav', data, samplerate)
```

Comment: Не работает с файлами .ogg